# Mysql how can i sql two tables and count groupid from the second

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, where-clause

I'm trying to make an Sql , that get all data from first table "posts_main" and then get the count of comments from second table "posts_comments"

I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts_main, count(posts_comments.groupid)
INNER JOIN posts_comments ON posts_comments.groupid = posts_main.id
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id'
GROUP BY posts_main.id";
```

Please, how can i do that ?

thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below query.

```
$sql = "select posts_main.*, 
(select groupid from posts_comments where groupid = posts_main.id group by groupid ) as count_group 
from posts_main 
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id' ";
```

Comment: NOW i want to add to "posts_main" table , the count of comments from the "posts_comments" table

Comment: For every comments?

Comment: In that above query will return the all the details from post_main and number of comment for that post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with subquery

```
SELECT posts.*,cnt FROM posts_main  
INNER JOIN (select posts_comments.groupid,count(posts_comments.groupid) as cnt
group by posts_comments.groupid)a
ON a.groupid = posts_main.id
WHERE posts_main.user_id = '$user_id'
```

Comment: when i use like this :
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts_main WHERE user_id='$user_id'";

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: $obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
 $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $obj->table, $obj->limit);
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->get_result();
 $outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 echo json_encode($outp);

Comment: i got data , but when i used the other sql, nothing back, no data and no error

Comment: show your sample data, otherwise it is difficult to identify why no result is showing

Comment: the data back as JSON, but when tried your SQL , nothing back at all

Comment: [{"id":1,"date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","user_id":1,"categories":"'general'","title":","media_url":"mobile_1.jpg","allow_comment":0}